# Add form with jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax

I got question about jquery form, I got code that *enable / disable* and change color onclick.
So now I only need to create link `(href="#")` in jquery that will create form *play / display*, my idea is creating form that enable edit text when i click disable it'll change the text to enable and color (which I did), and when I click edit image it will allow me to edit text..

Thanks all & here is my code:
js code

```
function changecolor(element){
if (element.innerHTML == "Disabled"){
    element.innerHTML = "Enabled";
    element.style.color = "green";
} else {
    element.innerHTML = "Disabled";
    element.style.color = "red";
}
return false;
```

}

HTML:

```
<h1>Edit Status: 
                 <a href="#" id="edit" onClick="return changecolor(this)" style="color: red;"><font id="enable">Disabled</font></a>
            </h1>
```

Comment: I need to add it, i dont have it atm.. that why i asking for it..

Comment: First thing is your code in `javascript` not in `jquery` and please clarify actually what you want?

Comment: i wrote down in answer number 1

Comment: It's extremely unclear what you are actually asking for here, you want to have a form, with a text input, and a button to enable/disable it, is that right? You are looking for a way to dynamically add the form with this functionality?

Answer (score 0):

```
fxnChangeColor = function () {
    $("a").click(function () {
        if ($(".c1").css("color") == "red") {
            $(".c1").css("color", "green")
        }
        else { $(".c1").css("color", "red") }
    });
};
```

Comment: I dont need to fix that, that already working -_-, i need to add form lets say in green that will circle the text, so when i click enable it will show up, and when i click disable it will hide.

Answer (score 0):

If i understand it correctly, you can achieve this by doing (with jQuery):

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#enable").on("click", function(){
        if($(this).text() == "Disabled"){
            $(this).text("Enabled").css({color: "green", background: "red"});
        }else{
            $(this).text("Disabled").css({color: "red", background: "none"});
        }

    });
});
```

Replace your code with this.
Use the latest jQuery version available.